# Why this won't get faster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I had this everywhere in all controllers, and views.

```
if current_user
    transaction
end
```

It's probably up to 100 if statement with current_user.

So I added this this below to application_controller then I replaced all `current_user` with `@current_user`

```
before_filter :current_user_set

def current_user_set
    if current_user
        @current_user = current_user
    end
end
```

However, it seems there's no change:( It didn't speed up. Why?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Zajn I thought that it was issuing many sql when I was using `current_user` so that I defined `@current_user = current_user` in the beginning of every action(application_controller). I was expecting there will be less sql and make this faster

Comment: It really depends on what current_user is. You don't mention at all where it comes from. However, most sane implementations of authentication that provide a current_user method already `@current_user ||= some.expression.to.find.current_user` so you aren't adding anything other than extra method calls.

Comment: Sorry for lack of my explanation. I use the gem called "devise" for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

When you get the current user information put it in the session instead of pulling it from the database which is what it sounds like you are doing, correct me if I have misunderstood the issue. So after the user is known:

```
session[:user] = @user
```

If your sessions are in your database this is ok since the user info won't be sent to the browser in a cookie, otherwise you can just put the user object id in the cookie or maybe the user_id or email field but that means you would have to retrieve the user by user_id or email every time you need the whole user object in your application, more SQL...

In your application_controller reference the session for the user

```
def current_user
    session[:user]
end
```

You can do other checks to make sure the user is logged in or present, etc...

Hopefully this helps, your questions is not quite clear.

Comment: Sorry for lack of my explanation. I use the gem called "devise" for authentication.

Comment: I have not used "devise" so I can't help with that, I hope someone who happens upon this question can help you out.